# Dropzone js - windows don't support attach doc, xls files

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js, dropzone

I use `dropzone.js` my site. And I use this params:

```
acceptedFiles:
'application/msword,
 application/vnd.ms-excel,
 application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,
 application/docx,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,
 application/pdf',
```

But, windows resolve choose only `pdf` file. This display on picture
[image]

If I switch to `All files` and choose `doc`, dropzone js display error (file types don't supported)

And I try to use code `acceptedFiles: 'application/*`. But problem not fix.

Browser google chrome.
And NOT problem on Ubuntu 16.04 and Mac OS. Only Windows. Help me please.

Answer (score 3):

Oh, windows resolve next format:

```
acceptedFiles:
    '.doc, .docx, .pdf, .xls, .xlsx, 
    application/msword, 
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,
    application/vnd.ms-excel,
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,
    application/pdf',
```